# More Complicated Authentication for Hangfire Dashboard

Tags: asp.net, hangfire

I am using hangfire on an app and I have the need to do dashboard auth using my repositories. To do that, I have to resolve the repository inside Hangfire's Authorize method but, using `OwinContext` I haven't been able to do so. I chose to use SimpleInjector for this project, and since it registers everything during `WebApiConfig`s `Register` method, I want to reach it. Recently I used a `middleware` as `MessageHandler` and from that, I successfully resolved a dependency using `HttpRequestMessage`. But on `OwinContext` I can't reach it and resolve a dependency through it using `HttpRequestMessage.GetDependencyScope()`.

This is how Hangfire suggests to do the auth for Asp.net apps on their documentation;

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        // In case you need an OWIN context, use the next line, `OwinContext` class
        // is the part of the `Microsoft.Owin` package.
        var owinContext = new OwinContext(context.GetOwinEnvironment());

        // Allow all authenticated users to see the Dashboard (potentially dangerous).
        return owinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Since I am using `Angular` on the front-end this `owinContext.Authentication.User` is null. And even if it wasn't, I only want myself to reach to the dashboard. So this wouldn't solve my problem.

How can I resolve my dependencies here inside `Authorize` method?

I cannot do it through constructor injection, because for hangfire, you are saying `UseHangfireDashboard` on the `Startup.cs`s `Configuration` as below states;

This is my `Startup.cs` file

```
private IEnumerable<IDisposable> GetHangfireServers()
{
    Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UseSqlServerStorage("CONN_STR", new SqlServerStorageOptions
        {
            CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
            UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
            DisableGlobalLocks = true
        });

    yield return new BackgroundJobServer();
}

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseHangfireAspNet(GetHangfireServers);
    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions { 
        Authorization = new [] { 
            new DashboardAuthorization() 
            /* explanation */ 
            // for DI to work through constructor, 
            //I have to give my AuthRepository as a parameter here. 
            //And my AuthRepository also has many DIs so, 
            //it's not possible through here.
        }
    });

    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello world from Hangfire!"));

}
```

My project is a .Net Framework 4.7.2 project by the way.

Comment: Did you try constructor injection? Did it work? What was the result?

Comment: No, in order to do that, I have to give it from the `Startup.cs` and I seem to be not able to do that.

Comment: Why? When you're not able to do something, please be clear about what's preventing you.

Comment: @mason I edited the question to show why, thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: Why can't you just ask your container to resolve you an instance of DashboardAuthorization in your Startup.cs, which can provide all the dependencies via constructor injection? Then you'd pass that instance of DashboardAuthorization to your Hanfire config

Comment: Not sure `Startup` can have a constructor with parameters, to resolve depedencies. I tried it and it shows me an error that says `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.` for `Startup`. So it doesn't work that way.

Comment: I didn't say Startup should have constructor parameters. I said your MyAuthorizationFilter needs constructor injection. Your Startup.cs should be where you setup your DI container.  Right? Or are you doing that somewhere else?

Comment: No, in my project the DIs are done inside `WebApiConfig.cs` which is a different file from the `Startup.cs`.

Comment: Move it! You want your DI setup to be as early as possible so that everything that can get an instance of the container can get it. Startup.cs is about as early in the pipeline as you can get it. You can then pass your container to your WebApiConfig.cs so that Web API can get properly wired up for DI, and still use same container for Hangfire's configuration (and job activator too!)

Comment: How to do that exactly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674343/owin-startup-class-is-being-executed-along-with-webapiconfig-register-method my structure is similar to this question, `AppStart` has this `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyService.App_Start.Startup))]` at the top, how can I put this and `WebApiConfig.cs` file's functions inside a single file and make it work?

Comment: You don't need to put them in a single file. In your Startup.cs, instantiate your DI container and register your services. Then you can pass that container to the Web API config, to Hangfire config, and to wherever else you need it.

Comment: Hi @mason. thank you for your guidance, I did move some stuff to make it work and it seems to work. If you'd like you can add this as an answer and I'll +1 it and accept. Thanks again :) Junior dev questions can sometimes be overwhelming I know lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Hangfire is concerned, you are responsible for providing an instance of the class that implements IDashboardAuthorizationFilter. So if that class has dependencies that you want to inject, that will be on you to wire up. It's probably best to register that type and its dependencies with your DI container, and have it resolve you an instance. That way it takes care of injecting all the dependencies for you via Constructor Injection.

You should end up with a pattern something like this in your Startup.cs where you configure the OWIN pipeline.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var container = CreateContainerWithRegisteredServices();
    var dashboardFilter = container.Resolve<IDashboardAuthorizationFilter>();

    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions { 
        Authorization = new [] { dashboardFilter }
    });

    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello world from Hangfire!"));

    // Configure Web API, SignalR, or whatever else hangs off your OWIN pipeline.
    // You can pass the container into their configure methods if necessary.   
}

IContainer CreateContainerWithRegisteredServices()
{
    //this method will look different depending on your chosen IoC library
    var container = SomeIoCLibrary.CreateContainer();
    container.Register<MyAuthorizationFilter, IDashboardAuthorizationFilter>();
    //register other dependencies here

    return container;
}
```